# Android Studio: IDE Fatal Errors. Doesn't auto suggest + compiles app somewhat wrong

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am no expert in dealing with such stuff (fixing IDE's) but I got 116 of these exceptions:

> Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove
>   discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in
>   java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but
>   their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy)
>   are not equal.This violates the general contract of
>   java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's
>   documentation. object #1 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0] (class
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
>   hashCode=1492582784; object #2 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0]
>   (class
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
>   hashCode=1492582784: Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During
>   rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be
>   equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or
>   TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those
>   calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates
>   the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point
>   two in that method's documentation. object #1
>   =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0] (class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
>   hashCode=1492582784; object #2 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0]
>   (class
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
>   hashCode=1492582784

Even after restarting IDE it still gives me problems.
It doesn't auto suggest or fill variables/functions etc.. I have to make my app literally just from remembering things, how can I fix this? It's quite annoying.

I noticed it's thrown every time I press Ctrl+Space (for auto suggest).

Help?

Update:

```
> Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove
> discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in
> java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but
> their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy)
> are not equal.This violates the general contract of
> java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's
> documentation. object #1 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0] (class
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784; object #2 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0]
> (class
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784: Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During
> rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be
> equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or
> TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those
> calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates
> the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point
> two in that method's documentation. object #1
> =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0] (class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784; object #2 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0]
> (class
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Equal objects
> must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove discovered that the
> following two objects claim to be equal (as in
> java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but
> their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy)
> are not equal.This violates the general contract of
> java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's
> documentation. object #1 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0] (class
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784; object #2 =PsiArrayAccessExpression:args[0]
> (class
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiArrayAccessExpressionImpl),
> hashCode=1492582784   at
> gnu.trove.TObjectHash.throwObjectContractViolation(TObjectHash.java:318)
>   at gnu.trove.THashMap.rehash(THashMap.java:350)     at
> gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:283)    at
> gnu.trove.THashMap.put(THashMap.java:175)     at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.guess.impl.GuessManagerImpl$2.visitTypeCastExpression(GuessManagerImpl.java:177)
>   at
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiTypeCastExpressionImpl.accept(PsiTypeCastExpressionImpl.java:98)
>   at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:61)
>   at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:26)
>   at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.walkChildren(WalkingState.java:65)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.WalkingState.elementStarted(WalkingState.java:52)
>   at
> com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.elementStarted(PsiWalkingState.java:70)
>   at
> com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.visitElement(JavaRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.java:34)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.guess.impl.GuessManagerImpl$2.visitElement(GuessManagerImpl.java:198)
>   at
> com.intellij.psi.JavaElementVisitor.visitCodeBlock(JavaElementVisitor.java:68)
>   at
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiCodeBlockImpl.accept(PsiCodeBlockImpl.java:202)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.guess.impl.GuessManagerImpl.getAllTypeCasts(GuessManagerImpl.java:171)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.guess.impl.GuessManagerImpl.getControlFlowExpressionType(GuessManagerImpl.java:380)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionUtil.getQualifierCastType(JavaCompletionUtil.java:416)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionUtil.processJavaReference(JavaCompletionUtil.java:355)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor$5.consume(JavaCompletionContributor.java:312)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor$5.consume(JavaCompletionContributor.java:300)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.processReference(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:123)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.LegacyCompletionContributor.processReferences(LegacyCompletionContributor.java:106)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor.addReferenceVariants(JavaCompletionContributor.java:300)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(JavaCompletionContributor.java:239)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:84)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:132)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:125)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:112)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaNoVariantsDelegator.fillCompletionVariants(JavaNoVariantsDelegator.java:46)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:84)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:132)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:125)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplateCompletionContributor$1.addCompletions(LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.java:75)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProvider.addCompletionVariants(CompletionProvider.java:36)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(CompletionContributor.java:155)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:84)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.performCompletion(CompletionService.java:115)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.calculateItems(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:769)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.access$900(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:84)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator$1CalculateItems.run(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:751)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1$1$1.run(CompletionThreading.java:93)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:911)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1$1.run(CompletionThreading.java:88)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>   at
> com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1.run(CompletionThreading.java:84)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Comment: Please file a bug at b.android.com. If you can provide a full stack trace of that exception it would be most helpful.

Comment: @ScottBarta and how do I do that?

Comment: So how do I fix this? Or how do I continue working on my app?

Comment: If (File Menu) Invalidate Caches/Restart doesn't fix it, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking at this years after and still unable to find a solution, I faced the same issue and ended up working it out. See below if you had a similar case to mine.

My issue was with using JSONObject and JSONArray objects. Basically, I would read, for instance, a JSONObject, and try to get another JSONObject within the first one like so

Say you are reading this message:

```
{
    "sub1": ["array element 1", "array element 2", "array element 3"],
    "sub2": {
                "name": "name for sub-object sub2",
                "value": "value for sub-object sub2 or whatever"
            }
}
```

Let's say that the entire object is given to me in `args[0]`, then what I was doing to read it was this:

```
JSONObject globalObject = (JSONObject) args[0];
JSONArray sub1= (JSONArray) globalObject.get("sub1");//<-- the problem
JSONObject sub2 = (JSONObject) globalObject.get("sub2");//<-- also the problem

String arrayElement1 = sub1.get(0);
String nameSub2 = sub2.getString("name");
```

**Solution**
The problem came from casting the content from a JSONObject/JSONArray's `get()` method,  into a JSONObject/JSONArray. There's no need to do that as you can just do `getJSONObject(/*value*/)` or `getJSONObject(/*value*/)`, and obtain a result that's already of type `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`

So my code above should look something like this:

```
JSONObject globalObject = (JSONObject) args[0];//<--only this needs to be casted
JSONArray sub1= globalObject.getJSONArray("sub1");//<-- got rid of the castnig
JSONObject sub2 = globalObject.getJSONObject("sub2");//<-- no more casting

String arrayElement1 = sub1.get(0);
String nameSub2 = sub2.getString("name");
```

Hope this helps someone.